# How do I set up IntelliJ IDEA to redeploy changed resources?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ IDEA and want that my class should be redeployed after I make changes. Eclipse can do this. How does this work in IDEA?

I know that in the run configuration there is "On frame deactivation" and I set it to "Update classes and resources", but this does not work.

Do you hit the "redeploy" button every time you made a change in your class?

Comment: May be this helps https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/updating-applications-running-on-application-servers.html

Answer (score 3):

There are limitations to class reload, in any Java project.  It also depends on what you're using to perform this reload (if you're using a servlet container, etc).

By default, IntelliJ uses HotSwap for its reloading.  There are some limitations to it though:

> At the moment due to original limitations of Java SDK the HotSwapping is possible ONLY if a method body is altered. In all other cases (like changing method or class signature), the class reload is impossible and the corresponding error message appears.

That said, the instructions for configuring your application to reload [can be found here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/reloading-classes.html).

> **To configure reloading behavior**
>
> 1. On the main menu, choose File | Settings , and then expand the Debugger node.
> 2. Open HotSwap page.
> 3. Click one of the radio buttons in the group Reload classes after compilation. You can opt to always reload classes, reload after
>      confirmation, or never do it.

Comment: Also i would suggest to use [jrebel plugin](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/display/?utm_source=google-c&utm_medium=text&utm_campaign=jrebel-dl&gclid=Cj0KEQjw6cCuBRCh4KrGoJ6LoboBEiQAwzYsdLlX6BT74N3GrrQREfpzCj0thHXoTfROotxyEh7X5lwaAixl8P8HAQ) It has much more functionality that raw java.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at HotswapAgent configuration for [InteliJ IDEA](https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent/wiki/Intellij-IDEA-setup)